# Check String equality of Slide textbox

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I'm using `SlidesApp.getActivePresentation.getSlides[0].getPageElements()[0].asShape().getText().asString()` to get the text of the title of the slide. However, when I try to check the text in an equality statement like `SlidesApp.getActivePresentation.getSlides[0].getPageElements()[0].asShape().getText().asString() == "XYZ Company"` it returns `false`.  What do I need to do to accurately check that a given Slide page element textbox contains certain text?

Comment: What does `Logger.log()` of the value `SlidesApp.getActivePresentation.getSlides[0].getPageElements()[0].asShape().getText().asString()` actually output?

Comment: "XYZ Company" as a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the type of textbox was adding a trailing line break, so `s.getPageElements()[0].asShape().getText().asString().trim() == "XYZ Company"` evaluates `true`

Answer (score 1):

### Alternative Solution:

You can also try using the [JavaScript String includes()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp) method as it will only check if a string includes the word you're looking for & it will disregard any new lines or spaces on the string. See this sample below:

```
function test() {
  var slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[0].getPageElements()[0].asShape().getText().asString();
  Logger.log(slide.includes("XYZ Company"));
}
```

### Sample:

[image]

Comment: If we answered your question, you may also want to click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved & they'll easily see this post on their searches.

Comment: I found the answer and posted it with the "answer your own question" button and assumed that would automatically mark that as the Answer. I appreciate the suggestion, but I don't want the option of adding anything except the string "XYZ Company"